# MySQL - How to execute a subquery once to calculate many other fields?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The next *query* example calculates *totalSubjectToTax* and *totalExemptToTax*. For that purpose, *query* is doing a *subquery*, but repeating it in both calculations. How is it possible to obtain *totalSubjectToTax* and *totalExemptToTax* by executing *subquery* just once?

```
SELECT
    documentId,
    (
        SUM(IF(
            di.document_item_subjectToTax = true,
            di.document_item_amount,
            0
        ))
        * (1 - IFNULL((SELECT ... subquery code ...), 0))
    ) AS totalSubjectToTax,
    (
        SUM(IF(
            di.document_item_subjectToTax = false,
            di.document_item_amount,
            0
        ))
        * (1 - IFNULL((SELECT ... subquery code ... ), 0))
    ) AS totalExemptToTax
FROM document
LEFT JOIN document_item AS di ON di.document_documentId = documentId
GROUP BY documentId
```

*subquery* code:

```
SELECT
    SUM(document_discount_percentage / 100)
FROM document_discount
GROUP BY document_documentId
```

Data sample:

```
documentId
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6

document_documentId | document_item_subjectToTax | document_item_amount
                  1                         true                   1000
                  1                         true                   1500
                  2                         true                    500
                  3                        false                    600
                  3                         true                    900
                  4                        false                   2700
                  5                         true                    400
                  5                         true                   7000
                  6                        false                   2400
                  6                        false                   1100

document_documentId | document_discount_percentage
                  1                              5
                  3                             10
                  3                              5
                  6                              4
```

Expected result:

```
documentId | totalSubjectToTax | totalExemptToTax
         1                2375                  0
         2                 500                  0
         3                 510                765
         4                   0               2700
         5                7400                  0
         6                   0               3360
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show some sample of your actual data and clarification of what is not effective and what you are trying to get final results with.

Comment: What is not effective is that the query is not optimal, because it is executing the same subquery twice. I am having the result, but the process to obtain it is not optimal. Added the information asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with the subquery:

```
SELECT
    d.documentId,
    SUM(IF(
        di.document_item_subectToTax, 
        di.document_item_price * di.document_item_quantity, 
        0
    )) * IFNULL((1 - dd.totalDiscountPercentage), 1) AS totalSubjectToTax,
    SUM(IF(
        !di.document_item_subectToTax, 
        di.document_item_price * di.document_item_quantity, 
        0
    )) * IFNULL((1 - dd.totalDiscountPercentage), 1) AS totalNotSubjectToTax
FROM document AS d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        document_documentId,
        SUM(document_discount_percentage / 100) AS totalDiscountPercentage 
    FROM document_discount
    GROUP BY document_documentId
) AS dd ON d.documentId = dd.document_documentId
LEFT JOIN document_item AS di.document_documentId = d.documentId
GROUP BY d.documentId
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that prequeries just the document items into taxable or not, then left-joins to sum of discounts.  From that, computes multiplier.  For ex: Your item #3, you have a 10 and 5 which represents 15% off.  So when I sum the discount / 100 results in 10/100 = .1 + 5/100 = .05 = .15.  So when it comes to the final query, I multiply the taxable and nontaxable by 1 - .15 (in this case), getting an 85%.  Similar to the other ones in your data.

```
SELECT
      PreSum.documentId,
      PreSum.Taxable * ( 1 - coalesce( Discnt.DocDisc, 0 )) FinalTaxable,
      PreSum.NonTaxable * ( 1 - coalesce( Discnt.DocDisc, 0 )) FinalNonTaxable
   from
      ( select 
              di.documentId,
              SUM( case when di.document_item_subjectToTax then di.document_item_amount else 0 end ) as Taxable,
              SUM( case when NOT di.document_item_subjectToTax then di.document_item_amount else 0 end ) as NonTaxable
           from
              document_item di
           group by
              di.documentId ) PreSum
      LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT document_documentId,
               SUM( document_discount_percentage / 100.0 ) docDisc
           FROM document_discount
           GROUP BY document_documentId ) Discnt
        ON PrSum.DocumentID = Discnt.document_documentId
```

Comment: How to calculate the discount is not the subject of the question, which can result a bit confusing. Anyways indeed I had a mistake in discount calculation, which is fixed now, but thanks for pointing out.